# Mongodb logging level components

Tags: mongodb

I have a question about log level by components in mongodb 3.0. I want to avoid these loggings:

> 2016-10-03T17:38:03.935+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:47835 #23 (1 connection now open)
>   2016-10-03T17:38:34.271+0200 I NETWORK  [conn23] end connection 127.0.0.1:47835 (0 connections now open)

I can read in the documentation a new log level associated to each component, an example:

```
db.setLogLevel(1, "network" )
```

But i try all level without successful.

It is possible to avoid these loggings?

Where i can find a log level table with each level and numbers associated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [getLogLevelComponents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.getLogComponents/) command can be used to display the verbosity settings for the different log settings.

These log messages are classified as [informational](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.setLogLevel), the lowest log level setting available, so it may not be possible to exclude them.